# Weblogic 10 :- Waffle authentication JNA error

Tags: java, weblogic, waffle

I am trying to implement waffle authentication technique.
In that I am using following jars :-

1. jna-platform-4.0.0
2. jna-4.0.0
3. guava-16.0.1
4. slf4j-api-1.7.12
5. slf4j-simple-1.7.12
6. waffle-jna-1.7.3

Its working fine on local host.
But as soon as I deploy on integration server which is running on `Weblogic 10` I get the following error:-

```
Unable to load library 'Secur32': Native library (sunos-sparc/libSecur32.so) not found in resource path (:::/local/jdk/jdk1.7.0_65/lib/tools.jar:/apps/wls1213/wlserver/server/lib/weblogic_sp.jar:/apps/wls1213/wlserver/server/lib/weblogic.jar:/apps/wls1213/wlserver/../oracle_common/modules/net.sf.antcontrib_1.1.0.0_1-0b3/lib/ant-contrib.jar:/apps/wls1213/wlserver/modules/features/oracle.wls.common.nodemanager_2.0.0.0.jar::/apps/wls1213/wlserver/server/lib/xqrl.jar::)
```

Infact on localhost also I am using same weblogic 10 but its working fine there.

**My web.xml for authentication is :-**

```
<filter-class>waffle.servlet.NegotiateSecurityFilter</filter-class>

         <init-param>
            <param-name>principalFormat</param-name>
            <param-value>fqn</param-value>
        </init-param>

       <init-param>
        <param-name>roleFormat</param-name>
        <param-value>both</param-value>
       </init-param>

       <init-param>
        <param-name>allowGuestLogin</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>impersonate</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>securityFilterProviders</param-name>
            <param-value>
                waffle.servlet.spi.BasicSecurityFilterProvider
                waffle.servlet.spi.NegotiateSecurityFilterProvider
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>waffle.servlet.spi.NegotiateSecurityFilterProvider/protocols</param-name>
            <param-value>
                Negotiate
                NTLM
            </param-value>
        </init-param>

        <init-param>    
           <param-name>waffle.servlet.spi.BasicSecurityFilterProvider/realm</param-name>
           <param-value>image</param-value>
```

After adding this filter I am receiving this error.

Please help me to sought out this issue. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is `sunos-sparc/libSecur32.so` in your classpath or `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`? Have you tried editing your classpath?

Comment: From where I can get this so file ? From my localhost it search for libjnidispatch.so   But when I am deploying to integration, it searches for libSecur32.so which is not present in jar file.

Comment: From where I can get this so file ? From my localhost it search for libjnidispatch.so   But when I am deploying to integration, it searches for libSecur32.so which is not present in jar file.

Comment: @AviralSrivastava We encountered same problem. You got any solution?

Comment: did you get any solution for this problem ?